# React.JS Map data use Hooks useState to set data on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm passing data from App to my Store component... When the page loads im trying to useState to display the current products so I can then filter later. When I useEffect to this I'm getting a weird OBJ return and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

When I try and console.log(storeItems) in the functions filterBrand() & filterSize() im getting the console log of the 2nd/3rd OBJ. Not sure how to filter through that, honestly first time I've seen that...Trying to learn best practice so feel free to provide explanations / examples! Thank you :)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import StoreItems from "./StoreItems.jsx";
import Filter from "../Filters/Filter";

const Store = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
    const [storeItems, setStoreItems] = useState([]);
    const [productSize, setProductSize] = useState("");
    const [productBrand, setProductBrand] = useState("");
    const [productCount, setProductCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(products)

        const allProducts = products.map((product, i) => {
            return (
                <StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
            );
        })

        console.log(allProducts)

        setStoreItems(allProducts)

        console.log(storeItems)

    }, [])


    const filterBrand = (event) => {
        setProductBrand(event.target.value)
        console.log(event.target.value)
        console.log(storeItems)
    }

    const filterSize = (event) => {
        setProductSize(event.target.value)
        console.log(event.target.value)
        console.log(storeItems)
    }


    return (
        <main className="storeContent">
            <Filter products={products} productSize={productSize} productBrand={productBrand} productCount={productCount} filterBrand={filterBrand} filterSize={filterSize} />
            <div className="productContainer">
                {storeItems}
            </div>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Store;
```

posting screen shots of what it returns

[image: console picture]

1st console log is console.log(products)

2nd is console.log(allProducts)

3rd is console.log(storeItems)

Comment: does it render properly  ?

Comment: why are you storing all items in `allProducts` ?

Comment: it does render properly as seen in the screen shot, but I need to filter these by productBrand and productSize but the OBJ that is returning is 2nd OBJ in the img I attached so I'm curious why its doing that.. making it hard to parse the data

Comment: I'm really just trying to set the "products" OBJ to storeItems on page load, if I'm doing this wrong, please feel free to show how you would do this! Really curious and trying to learn BEST PRACTICE. newbie here hehe @emkarachchi

Comment: Does replacing `storeItems ` in the `return` statement with ```products.map((product, i) => {
            return (
                <StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
            );
        })```
works? and also you can use the `products` array to filter the data. Would be harder to filter data from rendered `UI components`

Comment: Are you asking in the actual HTML (JSX) code at the bottom?

Comment: Yes. try replacing the variable `{storeItems}` with `{products.map((product, i) => { return (<StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />); })}`

Comment: Yeah, that works, I was hoping to set it to "state" so I can use that to then filter through, is that good practice or naw? Also, would I just constantly use 
   {products.map(product => { ) })}
when filtering?

Comment: Aah... I get your point. change `const [storeItems, setStoreItems] = useState(products);` and change the map to `{storeItems.map((product, i) => { return (<StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />); })}`. whenevenr you want to filter data use `storeItems`. so it'll automatically re-render the view for you.

Comment: oh wow, been working on this for awhile now and that seems to return what I've been hoping for! Would I then use setStoreItems() when writing up my filter functions? ....answered my own question lol thanks again!

Comment: Yes. You can `setStoreItems(yourFilteredDataArray)` whenever you want to filter the data and if you want to reset the filter, just use `setStoreItems(products)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the following code in the `useEffect` method.

```
const allProducts = products.map((product, i) => {
    return (
        <StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
    );
})
```

To achieve expected behavior,

You can set `products` to your state in the `Store` component.

```
const [storeItems, setStoreItems] = useState(products);

useEffect(() => {storeItems(products)}, [products])
```

and you can use a simple method as follows to render data to the UI.

```
const renderProducts = () => {
    return storeItems.map((product, i) => {
        return (<StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />);
    })
}
```

Then in your `return` statement, just change the `storeItems` to `renderProducts()`. In the end your `return` should look as follows,

```
    return (
        <main className="storeContent">
            <Filter products={products} productSize={productSize} productBrand={productBrand} productCount={productCount} filterBrand={filterBrand} filterSize={filterSize} />
            <div className="productContainer">
                {renderProducts()} //This line is important.
            </div>
        </main>
    );
```

Then whenever you want to filter items, you can use something like,

```
const filterProductsByName = () => {
    let filteredProducts = storeItems.filter(function (item) {
        return item.name === "some product name";
    });
    setStoreItems(filteredProducts);
}
```

And if you want to go back to the original state, just use,

```
setStoreItems(products);
```

Comment: see I guess where I'm confused is Products dont render on intial start of project...sometimes if I save a file and it restarts/rerenders the project, no items show up.

Comment: Is there any errors showing up on the console ? .Try adding `useEffect(() => {storeItems(products)}, [products])`

Comment: added this in
 useEffect(() => {
        setStoreItems(products)
    }, [products])
and now I'm loading in with products!

Comment: I'm afraid with this method I'm unable to filter, or kinda understand how to filter

Comment: Okay figured out I was missing my event argument but I can only filter once ...


   const filterBrand = (event) => {
        setProductBrand(event.target.value)
        let filteredProducts = storeItems.filter(function (product, i) {
            if (product.name.includes(event.target.value)) {
                return (
                    <StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
                )
            } else {
                console.log("false")
            }
        });
        setStoreItems(filteredProducts);
    }

Comment: Please update the question with a sample of your product's object?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const filterBrand = (event) => {
        setProductBrand(event.target.value)

        let filteredProduct = products.filter(product => product.name.includes(event.target.value));
        setStoreItems(filteredProduct);
        setProductCount(filteredProduct.length)

        if (event.target.value === "All") {
            setStoreItems(products)
        };
    }
    const filterSize = (event) => {
        setProductSize(event.target.value)

        let filteredSize = products.filter(product => 
         product.name.includes(event.target.value));
        setStoreItems(filteredSize);
        setProductCount(filteredSize.length)


        if (event.target.value === "All") {
            setStoreItems(products)
        };
    }
```

these seem to work with filtering and productCount...

still trying to figure out why this returns 0 products

```
    const renderProducts = () => {
        return storeItems.map((product, i) => {
            console.log(product)
            return (
                <StoreItems key={i} product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
            );
        })
    }
```

Comment: Don't use the answer section to extend the question. Just update your question